# Inconsistent behavior of builtin when overloading built-in functions in Octave

Tags: matlab, function, octave, overloading

I am trying to overload some built-in functions in Octave to perform a custom action prior to calling the built-in version of the overloaded function. In MATLAB (and supposedly Octave), I can do this using the [`builtin`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Overloading-and-Autoloading.html) function.

The typical function definition would look something like this where I forward all inputs/outputs to/from the built-in after doing my custom action:

```
function varargout = disp(varargin)
    % Do a custom thing
    fprintf('Calling overloaded disp!\n')

    % Now call the builtin
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('disp', varargin{:});
end
```

Now if I place this file (`disp.m`) on my path, any function which calls `disp` will execute my overloaded version which prints out extra information before calling the built-in `disp` function.

```
>> disp('hello world')
Calling overloaded disp!
hello world
```

The issue I'm having is that this works for *some* built-ins but not all. For example, if I try to overload `figure`.

```
function varargout = figure(varargin)
    disp('Creating a figure!')

    [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('figure', varargin{:});
end
```

When I call this, `builtin` calls the *the overloaded function again* rather than the true built-in.

```
>> figure()
Creating a figure!
Creating a figure!
Creating a figure!
...
error: max_recursion_depth exceeded
```

Interestingly, if I overload `figure` as a command-line function rather than saving it in `figure.m` it behaves exactly as I would expect.

```
> function varargout = figure(varargin), disp('here'), [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('figure', varargin{:}), endfunction
> figure()
here
```

Now one thing I noticed while debugging this was that Octave (obviously) issues a warning when you have a function with the same name as a built-in. If you look at the warnings, they are slightly different for the ones that function overloading works and does not work for:

> warning: function ./disp.m shadows a built-in function  <-- WORKS
>   warning: function ./figure.m shadows a core library function  <-- DOES NOT WORK

The documentation does not seem to make any distinctions between core library functions and built-in functions and this behavior is not mentioned in the documentation for `builtin`.

Does anyone have any idea what causes this behavior and have any suggestions for how I can work around this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`builtin` only works for builtin functions. As you already understood, the problem is in the distinction between a builtin and a core library function.

Builtin function are built into the Octave interpreter itself.

Core library functions are functions that are distributed with Octave which includes, but is not limited to, the builtin functions.  The other core library functions includes all functions written in the Octave language (m files) and dynamically linked functions (oct files).  These other functions are not part of the Octave interpreter and only work because their directories are added to the Octave path.

Use `which` or `exist` to find out whether a function is builtin:

```
octave> which disp
'disp' is a built-in function from the file libinterp/corefcn/pr-output.cc
octave> which figure
'figure' is a function from the file /home/carandraug/.local/share/octave/4.1.0+/m/plot/util/figure.m
octave> which audioread 
'audioread' is a function from the file /home/carandraug/.local/lib/octave/4.1.0+/oct/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/audioread.oct

octave> exist ("disp", "builtin")
ans =  5
octave> exist ("figure", "builtin")
ans = 0
octave> exist ("audioread", "builtin")
ans = 0
```

Of course, there is no promise that a function will remain a builtin or m file function between versions (although the reality is that this rarely changes).

Note that the logic is the same in Matlab but the set of builtin functions will be different.

Now the bit that I don't understand, is why does `builtin` behaves different at the Octave prompt. Independent of that, you can then just define your shadowed functions at `.octaverc`:

```
$ tail -n 5 ~/.octaverc 
function varargout = figure (varargin)
  mlock ();
  disp ("here");
  [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin ("figure", varargin{:});
endfunction
$ octave
octave> figure
here
```

Comment: Thanks for the great response as that clears things up very nicely. That being said, is there a good alternative for overloading these core functions? For example there is `run` for scripts.

Comment: @Suever unfortunately, I'm not aware of any good alternative. There are ugly workarounds (see my edit).

Comment: Thanks for the update! Definitely ugly workaround, but I guess that's what we get for trying to overload built-ins!

Comment: @Suever I take back what I said. If you define your functions in the `.octaverc` file, you can shadow the core functions. I'm still trying to figure out why builtin behaves different in a m file and in the interpreter though.

Comment: I wish I could upvote again! Thanks for investigating this and the `.octaverc` is a very suitable solution for me.

Comment: @carandraug So is there a way to call a function that has been shadowed but is not built-in, such as [`vpa`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58727452/2586922)?

Comment: @LuisMendo I'm not familiar with any method to do so that works for all cases. You could do things like manipulating the path (in a unwind_protect block) but if you have multiple functions being shadowed, using each other, and you only want to call one of them it won't work. It also won't work if it's being shadowed by a function in the current directory or if it's a function defined in the interpreter and not on a file.

Comment: @carandraug Thanks for your comments!