# How to call a shadowed function in Octave?

Tags: function, octave, symbolic-math

I want to modify the behaviour of the `vpa` function. For that I define my own function called `vpa` that calls the original `vpa` function and then does some more stuff.

To call the original function from within my modified function I use

```
y = builtin('vpa', varargin{:});
```

where `varargin` is a cell array of the function inputs, as usual.

The problem is that the above produces a different result than calling the original `vpa` function.

[Minimal example](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/rCBRI9pEwTRWR8HIQJMrqTQzpyQzT0MdKK6uA5EAiv//DwA), run on Octave 4.2.2:

```
>> vpa([4 5], 20)
ans = (sym) [4.0  5.0]  (1x2 matrix)
>> builtin('vpa',[4 5], 20)
ans = (sym) 4.0000000000000000000
```

The [same happens](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/QsFWobgyV8NC05orJbO4QKNCkyupNDOnJDNPQx0koK6jUKH5/z8A) with `disp` for symbolic arguments:

```
>> x = sym(8);
>> disp(x)
  8
>> builtin('disp', x)
 <class sym>
```

Why is the output different? Doesn't `builtin` really call the original function? If so, how can I call the original function?

---

[Related question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37861252/2586922).

Comment: Does `old_vpa = @vpa` work as a workaround?

Comment: @AndrasDeak I can't get that to work, even defining `old_vpa` as `global` before the intercepting function. I get a maximum-recursion-depth error. It seems that `old_vpa` points to the modified `vpa`,  not the original one. Maybe I'm making some mistake; I thought that approach should work. Anyway I would prefer a solution involving only code within the modified function

Comment: @AndrasDeak In [this example](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/PSc/KTFHIT8nJb6sIFHBVsEBSFlzcQFJjWhTBbNYTa6UzOICDXVdXXVNLqgyjWhzBQtUGa600rzkksz8PIVKW5CKssSixKL0zDxNLgUgQLXFGixWCbQMZh5MdbVVrSZEFmK0R2ol0OzUvBSSHfT/PwA) there's no recursion error; but, strangely, calling `old_vpa` outside the new function after the new function has been defined seems to actually call the new function, not the old

Comment: @Cris So how to call the non-builtin function?

Comment: OK, I’m starting to get the subtlety here. This is not about builtin/core,  it about overload resolution. `builtin` will always call the non-overloaded (non-class specific) version of a function. You use it from an overloaded function to call the base function. You are trying to call a shadowed overloaded function. Not sure if that is possible.

Comment: Note that function handles reference a non-overloaded function, and when called, normal overload resolution is used. So you end up calling the current overload for a function, not the one that existed when you created the handle. (At least this is how it works in MATLAB).

Comment: @Cris It would suffice if I could call a function by the full path of its file (which is known using `which`)

Comment: You can `run` a script, but that doesn't work for functions. I don't think it is possible to do what you want to do. I hope someone proves me wrong! :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'll probably end up manually copying the code of the functions I want to call :-)

Comment: not sure if this helps, but for the case of 'disp', you can get the right result by doing `builtin( '@sym/disp', x)`. This does not help with `vpa` in the same way, unfortunately, since vpa isn't an overload of an existing builtin in the same way that disp is.

Comment: btw, does something like `vpa2k = @(varargin) vpa(varargin{:})` also fail the same way as the `old_vpa = @vpa` strategy?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Good to know about `builtin( '@sym/disp', x)`, thank you! Using `@(varargin) vpa(varargin{:})` seems to [cause a recursion error](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/PSc/KTFHIT8nJb6sIFHBVsFBoyyxKLEoPTNPUwEoAudVW9VqWnNxgYSiTRXMYjW5UjKLCzTUdXXVNbmg2jWizRUsUGW40krzkksy8/MUKm2RjdPkUgACVNutwWKVQEfAzEO1HCQLMdojtRJodmpeCskO@v8fAA)

Comment: I guess you found a bug in octave and looking at what I consider the function actually implementing `builtin` I found this comment: `// FIXME: Note that if a function call returns multiple // values, and there is further indexing to perform, then we are // ignoring all but the first value.  Is this really what we want to // do?  If it is not, then what should happen for stat("file").size, // for exmaple?` Might be worth a bug report.

Comment: @Daniel From the comments above, it seems that `builtin` calls the non-class specific function, whereas I want to call a class-specific shadowed function. So I’m not sure anymore if `builtin` is what I should use. This said, yes, that “fixme” sounds like something that should be... fixed :-)